# Regarding const qualifier in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I am not able to understand the error as to why does it not accepting `const` qualifier

```
[Error] passing 'const abc' as 'this' argument of 'int abc::getarea()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Here is the code below.

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class abc{
    public:

    abc(){
    }

abc(int a,int b){

      length=a;
      height=b;
    }
    int getarea(){

        return length*height;
    }
     bool operator <(const abc&) const;

      private:
       int length;
       int height;  
    };
     bool abc::operator <(const abc& d) const{

       return getarea() < d.getarea();

     }


     int main(){

       abc a(10,12);
       abc b(13,15);
       if(a < b)
       cout << "\n B has larger volume";
       else
       cout << "\n A has larger volume"; 


        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: `getarea()` must also be `const` to pass it a `const` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`int abc::getarea()` is not marked as `const` but it is being called on a const object from one of its `const` member functions. You should mark `getarea` member function as `const` because it does not change the state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

`getarea` is not `const`, so it can't be called on `const` objects (or `const` references thereto). To fix the problem, declare it `const`:

```
int getarea() const {
    //        ^^^^^
    return length*height;
}
```